Undesired Chinese Font in Use, How to Search for it via Linux Terminal?
I'm pretty new to Linux & working with a terminal, so beginner-friendly answers would be appreciated :) !
Recently, I've had a problem with how my Chinese characters are displayed in certain programs, which end up using a font called "KouzanBrushFontGyousyu". I deduced this simply by comparing the font to several test fonts in a writer document. I'm also assuming it's technically a Japanese font, as not all characters can be used with it. It will look like this:

It's not been a consistent change, either; some programs will occasionally use this font, others don't ever. The only program that has consistently shown Chinese text using this font is Discord, which has been extremely jarring as it is a more artistic font and difficult to read.
I did transport some external fonts into a shared user folder using this tutorial months ago, but the font in question was not even one of them, and the problem only came up very recently. (I'm actually not even sure where this font came from or whether it is a system font?)
I have also tried to resolve this issue by following this tutorial, which has not helped.
I've now been thinking that I would like to try and search for where this font has even been at all used in my settings, but I'm not sure how. Is there a way to search for this "KouzanBrush" font through a command in the terminal, e.g. find? If I find where this font has been placed in certain configurations, I could maybe just switch it out or delete it. (This is my beginner brain speaking, I'm not sure how it actually works. It's just my current plan of action for lack of better options.)
And last but not least, here's the system I'm currently working with:
 Kernel: 5.15.0-126-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.4.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 6.0.4
tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: muffin vt: 7 dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Linux Mint 21.3 Virginia
base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy

Thank you for everyone who has taken the time to read so far, and thank you in advance for any replies & help, which would be greatly appreciated.

How did you install Discord? In case you are using the snap app, does it help if you switch to the .deb app?

@ArchismanPanigrahi Hi, first of all, thank you for your reply!! I'm actually not quite sure which one I'm using. I installed it through the software manager provided by Linux and there via Flatpack. How do I check which app I'm using?

Run the comamnds snap list and flatpak list, and find out which one has discord.

@ArchismanPanigrahi Seems to be the flatpak one since it shows up there and it seems like the snap one isn't even installed, to begin with.

Does it help if you install the deb package? https://discord.com/api/download?platform=linux&format=deb
